# How can I make App Engine HTTP URL handlers callable internally only?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I have a set of different modules with HTTP URL handlers. Some module handlers are designed only for internal access and I use urlfetch to call them from other modules. How can I ensure that these handlers are not callable from the wider internet?

Task queues get around this by allowing you to add `login: admin` to their URL `app.yaml`. This allows you to be sure that a task queue can only be invoked via an internal task queue function call. Is there something similar I can do with my handlers? I don't want to have to share a secret between the API and its consumer.

Comment: @MichaelakoTecourt I am actually using the Go runtime.

Comment: I think a solution might be to check an App Engine HTTP header value that can't be faked. I wonder what that would be. I think I will rephrase the question.

Comment: The answer is likely here https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/appidentity/#Java_Asserting_identity_to_other_App_Engine_apps. I will post it when I confirm it works with the ago SDK.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/41864284/152630

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your URL handler read the `X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid` header value. It will be populated with the name of your App Engine app that called the handler via its url fetch method. Make sure the url fetch method that makes the call does *not* follow redirects.

[Click here for documentation associated with this.](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/appidentity/#Java_Asserting_identity_to_other_App_Engine_apps)

Here's my Go handler that achieves what I was looking for:

```
func internalOnlyHandler(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        c := appengine.NewContext(r)
        appID := appengine.AppID(c)
        headerAppID := r.Header.Get("X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid")
        if appID == headerAppID {
            h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        } else {
            http.Error(w, "403 forbidden", http.StatusForbidden)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

GAE has built-in admin auth:

developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/adminusers

Comment: How can I make one module's URL Fetch request pretend to be a request from an admin user when accessing the other module? This might be more convoluted than just sharing a secret between modules.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood what you meant by "internal access".  If you are just accessing from one module to another, just send a secret POST parameter and test for it.