# How to authenticate requests across internal App Engine modules?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authentication, urlfetch

I have an application in Google App Engine that consists in 2 modules (`A` and `B`). `A` handles user requests and it's available without authentication. `B` is a microservice that perform certain tasks when `A` requires it. So we have `A` making requests to `B` using `urlfetch`:

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
from google.appengine.api import app_identity
rpc = urlfetch.create_rpc()
urlfetch.make_fetch_call(
    rpc,
    "https://b-dot-my-project.appspot.com/some/url",
    method='GET', 
    follow_redirects=False,
    headers = {
        'X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid': 'my-project', 
    },
)
response = rpc.get_result()
```

`B`'s `app.yaml` looks something like:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes
service: b

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: my_module.app
  login: admin
  auth_fail_action: unauthorized
```

In the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/issue-requests#issuing_a_request_to_another_app_engine_app), they suggest:

> When issuing a request to another App Engine app, your App Engine app
>   must assert its identity by adding the header
>   X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid to the request. If you instruct the URL
>   Fetch service to not follow redirects, App Engine will add this header
>   to requests automatically.

No matter what I do, I keep getting a `401` when making this request. Both `A` and `B` are deployed in the same project. Tried setting `follow_redirects=False` and adding the headers `X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid` manually (though I didn't expect it to work for the reasons described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/appidentity/?csw=1#Asserting_Identity_to_Other_Systems#asserting_identity_to_other_app_engine_apps)), still not sure if the header is being set, as the logs for `B` don't include request headers and the failure condition happens before my handler module gets executed.

I would rather if possible to rely on `A` authenticating to `B` rather than just dropping the option `login: admin` and rely only on the header, as it is nicer to be able to call `B` from a project admin account (for debugging purposes for example).

Comment: Separate modules within the same app are not "...another App Engine app,...".  You can just do a urlfetch to a url within the app, with no header modifications.

Comment: And, shouldn't it be `module: b` instead of `service: b`?  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/converting

Comment: FWIW in this scenario I would create a task in module A and push it on a queue handled by module B instead of using urlfetch.

Comment: @Dan: if the original request needed content from a module B response, a taskqueue wouldn't provide that.  A urlfetch may be appropriate.

Comment: @GAEfan That's true

Comment: @GAEfan: `A` and `B` are 2 independent applications living in the same project, each with it's own auth policies and run on different instances. From `B` point of view, a call from `A` is just like any call from any other client, so authentication is a must. Besides that, `service:` is the new `module:` on `gcloud`: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appref#service

Comment: @DanCornilescu  I need the results from `B`.

Comment: @Xocoatzin did you eventually find the solution?

Comment: @Philoozushi Gave up and changed strategy (using [jwt](https://jwt.io/) )

Answer (score 0):

Instead of specifying `login: admin` in your config, use the python library instead: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.users  This way you can check for the app engine header first, and fallback to the admin google user.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of `login:admin`, you could check the header in module B request for `'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine; appid: s~my-project)'`.  That tells you it came from urlfetch, taskqueue, or cron job.

Comment: Pretty sure a 3rd party could forge the User-Agent header, you should use `X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid` instead: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/outbound-requests#request_headers 

Plus, as stated in the question, dropping `login:admin` would prevent me from making requests to `B` directly, a feature I'd rather keep

Comment: A third party could forge the 'X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid' header as well.

Comment: Well, no, the header is set by App Engine and it's not possible to change, that's stated in the documentation, [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/appidentity/#asserting_identity_to_other_app_engine_apps) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/outbound-requests#request_headers)

Comment: Then, you can just check for that header directly, instead of `login:admin`.